# Script component to convert Text file to Excel in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio, sql-server-2005

I would like help with a script component in Visual Studio 2005 to take a text file as a source and convert it to Excel file (output). The text file uses a ~ (tilde) as the column delimiter. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Also, can this be done without installing Excel on the server?  Any and all suggestions are welcome.

Below is sample I am having a problem with in the script component:

```
   Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim objExcel As Excel.Application
    Const xlDelimited = 1
    Const xlWorkbookNormal = -4143

    objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    objExcel.Visible = True

    objExcel.Workbooks.OpenText("D:\PROCESSPO~TP-4186", _
        , , xlDelimited, , , , , , , True, "~")

    objExcel.Workbooks("PROCESSPO~TP-4186").SaveAs( _
        "D:\ProcessPO.xls", xlWorkbookNormal)

    objExcel.Workbooks("ProcessPO.xls").Close()

    objExcel.Quit()
End Sub End Class
```

I keep getting an error stating that Excel.Application is not defined and I also get Option Strict On requires all vairable declarations to have an 'AS' clause. Can someone point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Look here:[Different Options for Importing Data into SQL Server](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1207)

Comment: Dalex, Thanks for the info. I will make use of this. You wouldn't happen to know how I can define each field as a specific data type and number of characters?  I have two records, one with 5 columns and second with 30 columns. Column 4 in first record needs to be string with 10 characters and column 4 in second record needs to be Date with 30 characters. In SQL Server I can easily define the columns but the challenge here is to define by field not by column. Any advice you can give would be greatly appreciate it!

Comment: You can use format file where you can describe column type and length: [format file description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191479.aspx)